# ASIHTTPRequest Integrate Twitter

Tags: iphone, objective-c, twitter

I need your help. I have been switching from various libraries trying to find the suitable one to integrate `Twitter` in my application.

A while back i found out that i could use `ASIHTTPRequest` to send tweets from my app. I need to know if there's any tutorial or sample code available.

And i have already looked at `share-kit` and i prefer to integrate `Twitter` using `ASIHTTPRequest`

note: I have created my project using `ARC`, and it shoudl support both `iOS4 and 5`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twitter's documentation says that you have to make GET or POST HTTP requests with the appropriate form data (key-value pairs). For example, to post a status update, you can do:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/update.json"];
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];

[request addRequestHeader:@"Accept" value:@"*/*"];
[request addRequestHeader:@"onnection" value:@"close"];
[request addRequestHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"];
[request addRequestHeader:@"Content-Length" value:@"17"];
[request addRequestHeader:@"Host" value:@"api.twitter.com"];

[request setPostValue:@"User's new status" forKey:@"status"];

// set here completion/error handlers

[request startAsynchronous];
```

More documentation on Twitter's REST/HTTP API: https://dev.twitter.com/docs

For authetication, you'll need some kind of OAuth library. Here's Karl Adam's MPOAuth, with few additions and corrections by me: https://github.com/H2CO3/MPOAuthiOS

On iOS 5.x, you can use Apple's default, and easy to use Twitter.framework: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Twitter/Reference/TwitterFrameworkReference/_index.html

Comment: So will i be able to post a tweet using MPOAuthiOS only ?

Comment: Can we download a sample/example implementation of MPOAuthiOS ?

Comment: The implementation is on the github page I linked. Read the README, it has a Twitter sample.